# Changing the x and y rotation weirdly changes the z too in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a first person controller in Unity so that I know every single detail of it. I made the movement, but when I created the camera rotation i simply got stuck. Ok, it worked on the x axis, on the y axis, but why does the z axis also change?

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = Character.transform.position + offset;
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSpeed;
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSpeed;
    transform.Rotate(h, v, 0, Space.World);
}
```

Comment: `transform.position = Character.transform.position + offset;` is changing the x,y,z values

Comment: You could first rotate horizontally in world space transform.Rotate(0,h,0,Space.World); and then vertically in local space transform.Rotate(-v, 0, 0, Space.Self);

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it, and consider adding a tag to represent the language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with rotations and euler angles you have to understand that there are different coordinate spaces, like the object's local space and a world space. the x,y,z directions in world space will always look at the same direction, whereas the local space is the coordinate space of the local object (for example your camera). Thats why I would recommend you to rotate vertically in local space  and horizontally in world space.

```
transform.Rotate(0,h,0,Space.World);
transform.Rotate(-v, 0, 0, Space.Self);
```

Rotating your camera vertical in local space will change the object's local up axis (y-axis). this is why then rotating around that axis will give you your unwanted result. Just select the gameobject in your Scene view and observe it's local coordinate system while rotating and you might be able to better visually understand.

To also give you a simple,fun reallife example to observe yourself, sit upright on your office chair and look straight ahead and rotate on your chair. If you now look a little upwards or downwards and rotate your head instead you will notice a difference in rotation between rotating your neck and rotating on your chair, which should always have the same up-axis, which is different from the local up axis of your neck.

ps.: there are already many solutions to implement a first person camera, like in Unity's own standard assets, or [SmoothMouseLook](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SmoothMouseLook)
Looking at tutorials, following them and trying to understand them might bring you further than trying to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Euler angles are weird. When you rotate with euler angles, the rotations stack, and a rotation around one axis changes the other axis of rotation. It's best not to "add" euler angles (essentially what transform.Rotate() is doing) and best to work with them in absolute terms. In this case, your code should keep the "z axis" at 0 if you do the following:

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = Character.transform.position + offset;
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSpeed;
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSpeed;

    # Get the current euler angle in absolute terms
    Vector3 eulers = Character.transform.localEulerAngles;

    # now modify that euler angle, creating a new absolute euler angle
    eulers.x += h;
    eulers.y += v;
    eulers.z = 0;

    # and now assign the new euler angle back to the transform, overwriting the old value
    Character.transform.localEulerAngles = eulers;
}
```

In general I'd advise against using `Transform.Rotate()` for... most everything. I would also advise using quaternions wherever you're able. You don't need a complete understanding of quaternions for them to be very powerful.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, i can use quaternions for this code. Then what would it look like using quats?  (I ask this because i couldn't find a tutorial about quats that would make me fully understand the mechanics, and maybe this will help me a bit more)